# Automatic Translation when Converting Unicode to non-Unicode / NVARCHAR to VARCHAR

Tags: sql-server, collation, encoding, unicode

Unicode code point 9619 is a character called "Dark shade": `▓` (http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=9619).

Using the `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation and 1252 code page, I would expect that casting / converting that Unicode character to non-Unicode data type would result in a question mark (`?`) as code page 1252 does not appear to contain this character and this appears to be SQL Server's behavior when conversion can not take place.

So my question is: why does SQL Server convert this character to an ASCII code 166 which is "Pipe, Broken vertical bar": `¦` ?

```
SELECT NCHAR(9619), CAST(NCHAR(9619) AS CHAR(1)), ASCII(CAST(NCHAR(9619) AS CHAR(1)))
```

Comment: SQL Server uses what [this paper](https://www.owasp.org/images/d/d4/OWASP_IL_2007_SQL_Smuggling.pdf) calls homoglyphic transformation and often converts characters that can't be represented to near equivalents. Such as losing the accent on a character or changing smart quotes to plain quotes. I agree that doesn't look very close though! I'm not sure if or where these transformations are documented.

Comment: Wow, had no idea...jeez, just doesn't seem right...it's not the same character. Why not just an "...oops, no such character found in this code page..." and fail the conversion?

Comment: Just reading [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377(v=vs.110).aspx#replacement) and remembered this. Not sure if SQL Server uses exact same "best fit" algorithms.

Comment: @MartinSmith regarding not being sure of the "best fit" mappings for SQL Server, please see my [answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122375/30859) below as I found those mappings :-).

Answer (score 8):

> *Why does SQL convert Unicode 9619 to ASCII code 166?*

SQL Server is not employing any special custom logic here; it is using standard operating system services to perform the conversion.

Specifically, the SQL Server type and expression service (`sqlTsEs`) calls into OS routine [`WideCharToMultiByte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130.aspx) in `kernel32.dll`. SQL Server sets the input parameters to `WideCharToMultiByte` such that the routine performs a 'quick translation'. This is faster than requesting a specific default character be used when no direct translation exists.

The quick translation relies on the target code page to perform a *best-fit mapping* for any unmatched characters, as mentioned in [the link Martin Smith provided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx) in a comment to the question:

> Best-fit strategies vary for different code pages, and they are not documented in detail.

When the input parameters are set for a quick translation, `WideCharToMultiByte` calls OS service `GetMBNoDefault` ([source](http://fayaa.com/code/view/27558/raw/)). Inspecting the SQL Server call stack when performing the conversion specified in the question confirms this:

[image: SQL Server stack trace]

Answer (score 7):

Converting from Unicode data to a particular Code Page employs what is known as the "Best-fit" strategy (as noted in @Paul's [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/87046/30859) and in the link that @Martin noted in a comment on the Question). According to that MSDN page for [Character Encoding in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx#BestFit):

> Best-fit mapping is the default behavior for an Encoding object that encodes Unicode data into code page data...

But what exactly are these mappings? That MSDN page *used* to state the following:

> Best-fit strategies vary for different code pages, and they are not documented in detail.

However, that was not entirely correct. Perhaps the "strategies" for determining the mappings are not exactly documented. Ok. But, the mappings themselves *are* documented, just not in the easiest of places to find.

So, thanks to Microsoft moving the documentation to GitHub, that page now states the following (because I updated it 😸 ):

> Best-fit strategies are not documented in detail. However, several code pages are documented at the [Unicode Consortium's](https://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WindowsBestFit/) website. Please review the **readme.txt** file in that folder for a description of how to interpret the mapping files.

If you go to the following URL you will see a list of several files, each one named for the Code Page that it maps Unicode characters to:

ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WindowsBestFit/

Most of the files were last updated (or at least placed there) on 2006-10-04, and one of them was updated on 2012-03-14. The first part of those files maps ASCII codes into an equivalent Unicode Code Point. But the second part of each file maps the Unicode characters into their ASCII "equivalents".

I wrote a test script that uses the Code Page 1252 mappings to check if SQL Server is truly using those mappings. That can be determined by answering these two questions:

1. For all mapped Code Points, does SQL Server convert them into the specified mappings ?
2. For all unmapped Code Points, does SQL Server convert any of them into a non-"`?`" character?

The test script is too long to place here, so I posted it on Pastebin at:

[Unicode to Code Page mappings in SQL Server](http://pastebin.com/p318Zf2A)

Running the script will show that the answer to the first question above is "Yes" (meaning that all of the provided mappings are adhered to). It will also show that the answer to the second question is "No" (meaning, none of the unmapped Code Points convert into anything but the character for "unknown"). Hence, that mapping file is very accurate :-).